# Numbers with Prescribed type of Prime Factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, upper-lower-bounds

I know about some results providing some upper bounds for the cardinality of sets like $\mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{B}}(x):=\{n\leq x : p\mid n \Rightarrow p\in \mathcal{B}\}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the union of distinct reduce residues classes modulo $q$ (one of the most useful is due to Chang and Greg Martin: The smallest invariant factor of the multiplicative group, *Int. J. Number Theory* (2020), **16**, 182, 1377–1405.)

However, I was trying to get an upper bound for the set of positive integers $n\leq x$ for which $n$ has **exactly one** prime factor of the form $4k+3$.

I tried to use Chang and Martin result, but I was not able to do it.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can’t you just sun $\mathcal N_B(x/q)$ over all primes $q\le x$ congruent to $3$ mod $4$?